# Insert a value in database

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I am having a column named `no`. If I insert the `no`  in database same `no` should not insert, if it is stored in that table. please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the required column unique using `UNIQUE` constraint.

Your create table statement should be like:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col_1 datatype UNIQUE, col_2 datatype, .....)
```

This makes col_1 unique.

Answer (score 1):

set it as `Unique column` and `auto-increment`.

Answer (score 0):

A look on Google returns [Sql learning Basics](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/GcF9120312-Different-Types-of-SQL-Keys.html) and [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/05/sql-server-primary-key-constraints-and-unique-key-constraints/)

You can set your column auto increment property to on it will enable the column to add a unique incremental value for each new record other way to is add a primary key or unique key constraint to that particular column

Thanks

Comment: i have just guide the how to use constraints in your database table if you think it is not an answer please down vote it @NaveedS

Comment: you should have given some explanation along with the link. that's what suggested by SO.

Comment: i really don't know that if you have any link on SO where it is written lease forward me same and i dont want to debate on these things